# Xpath - how to find a cell in a table inside ambiguous DIV tags

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have the following html structure that is captured in this image :

[image: -]

How do I get to the cell value (for example: "$8.68 redeemed") in table? Tables are under two different DIV tags.

Here is the XPATH I constructed but it does not get to table cell elements:

```
//div[@class='hcf-templateContainer']/div[@class='hcf-account-table-container'][1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]
```

I also tried this for:

```
//div[@class='hcf-account-table-container']/table[@class='hcf-account-table']/caption[contains(text(), 'Redemption History')]/../tbody/tr/td[1]
```

And this:

```
//div[@class='hcf-account-table-container']/table[@class='hcf-account-table']/caption[contains(text(), 'Redemption History')]/../tbody/tr/td[2]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post the html code rather the screenshot.

Comment: Make your question a [MCVE] so it can be answered.

Comment: _...get to the cell values..._ which cell values? _...under two different DIV tags..._ which two `<DIV>` tags?

Comment: Luis and DebanjanB, I have edited the question and now have an example pointing to which cell value I wanted to find. Supputuri already gave the right answer, still updated the question following your feedback. Let me know if this can be improved more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct xpath to get the cell data `$8.96 redeemed.`

```
//div[@class='hcf-account-table-container']//caption[contains(text(), 'Redemption History')]/parent::table/tbody/tr/td[2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback supputuri. Unfortunately, I get "no such element error" when trying to locate the element.

Comment: Not sure why it's not working for you. I tried with a quick sample similar to your screenshot and was able to identify the element successfully (see the attached screenshot).  Can you please check if the xpath working in the developer tool rather in the code by keeping a break point.

Comment: @Sohel Are you able to get this work? If not can you please post the entire html of the div with class='hcf-templateContainer'

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to Chrome Dev Tool for Xpath validation. It's helpful. Using it the XPath you gave works. I think it is the calling code I need to look into more to resolve the not finding element error.

Comment: Ok, I have corrected the calling code, now can get to the elements I wanted to following your xpath example, thank you Supputuri!